# Logos does not appear in same position

Tags: html, css

I have two logos, see picture below, which does not appear on the same column. The twitter icon appears some pixels to the right.

[image]

The code looks like this which inserts the icons:

```
<ul class="social">
        <li>
            <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
               class="facebook" 
                href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>


<ul class="social">
        <li>
            <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
               class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Twitter</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bloggfb{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

How do I get rid of the space infront of the twitter icon?

Comment: That "space" you see is just the centering.

Comment: But it does not appear on the fb icon?

Comment: The row with the FB icon is just as centered as the row with the Twitter icon.

Comment: But how come there is a space before the twitter icon?

Comment: There is space before the FB icon too. The Twitter icon just has more of it. http://i.imgur.com/pVMKeGw.png

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a possibility to adjust this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am looking at your site just now. Add this to your css and it works nice in Chrome at least:

```
 .social li a {
display: table;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image: After adding the abve CSS in inspector in my browser]

Comment: Hi preben, can you look at my site once more, now I have this text "Följ oss på" Which does not go along with the icons?

Comment: Do you want to move the icons under the headline, or the headline out to the icons?

To move the icons, edit this from 150 px to 0 px: 

`.Foljoss li a {
display: table;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}`

I still see there are more aligns to do. The gap between the FB-logo and the headline is little, and the gap between the FB and the Twitter icon is large.

Comment: Hi I want to move the text out to the icons, the text above the fb icon, the fb icon and the twitter icon. [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/blogga-om-oss/)

Comment: `.Foljoss .widget {
margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}`
That makes the gap between the logos less. Looks nicer in my eyes. 

Regarding moving the headline to above the icons: That looks strange on a smartphone.

Use this: 
`.Foljoss h3 {
margin-left: 150px;
}`
or use this to get more space between the headline and the icons:
`.Foljoss h3 {
margin-left: 150px;
margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}`

Comment: So you should add this in the bottom of a css file to make it look better in mobile display (less than 768 px width):

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.Foljoss li a, .Foljoss h3 {margin-left: 0px !important; }
}`
This means: when the screen is less than 768px, then use this css in stead.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Tackar för hjälpen :) I am using Custom CSS manager plugin, can I insert it there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68996/discussion-between-joneskvist-and-preben).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the images & text are centered (optical illusion).

When You change `text-align: center` to `text-align: left` everything should be ok

```
.bloggfb{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

If You still think it's not perfect You can always use `position: relative & absolute` combination like here:

```
 .bloggfb li{
     position: relative;
  }

.bloggfb i{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
}
```

Each `<i>` element will be positioned absolutely according to `<li>` element with 1px accuracy

Comment: I have already tested that, but if you look at the [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/blogga-om-oss/) again, it appears to much to the left.

Comment: It is still a white space infront of the twitter icon :/

Comment: IMHO it's ok but if You need better solution I will propse it in answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason:

```
.bloggfb {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you change this to `text-align: left;` both icon will render fine.

Comment: I have already tested that, but if you look at the [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/blogga-om-oss/) again, it appears to much to the left.

Comment: The reason for that is that in your container you have the following class: `col-sm-6`. Which means 50% of the available space.

Comment: Yes that is correct, is there any possibilities I can still adjust the twitter icon?

Comment: change the `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2`

Comment: Hm that is a bit hard for me since Im not really that good in coding. There is nothing I can adjust in the CSS? Or maybe give the twitter icon a new class name etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try giving the common width for both the element, if you feel the item is in left after giving the alignment to left.

Trying changing the below css alone to make it aligned and also to keep both the item in center:

```
.social {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 118px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this is how you would like the look should be:

[image]

Comment: That did not work, I can mention that I have class: `col-sm-6`. Which means 50% of the available space.

Comment: after changing the above css it worked for me. If you give the common width for the element then it will consider that. The elements width will be overridden with col-sm-6.